Error de seguridad de SSL
A ver si alguien me puede orientar, me heredaron una aplicación que está desarrollada en Visual Basic 6.0, ésta se conecta a 2 bases de datos en 2 estaciones remotas, no a la vez, sino a una o a la otra, con ADODB.Connection, y a una de ellas lo hace sin problema pero cuando se intenta conectar a la otra regresa el error: Error de seguridad de SSL.
En la que si se puede conectar es una BD SQL Express 2008 y la máquina tiene Windows 10
    Set ConnSV = New ADODB.Connection
    strConnSV = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & strServidorSQLB2 & "; " & _
    "uid=" & strUsuarioSQLB2 & ";pwd=" & strClaveSQLB2 & ";database=" & strCatalogoSQLB2
    ConnSV.ConnectionTimeout = 15
    ConnSV.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    ConnSV.Mode = adModeRead
    ConnSV.Open strConnSV

Donde strServidorSQLB2 es 'Bascula08\SQLEXPRESS'
En la que no se puede conectar es una BD SQL Express 2008 y la máquina tiene Windows 11 Pro
    Set ConnSV = New ADODB.Connection
    strConnSV = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & strServidorSQLB3 & "; " & _
    "uid=" & strUsuarioSQLB3 & ";pwd=" & strClaveSQLB3 & ";database=" & strCatalogoSQLB3
    ConnSV.ConnectionTimeout = 15
    ConnSV.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    ConnSV.Mode = adModeRead
    ConnSV.Open strConnSV

Donde strServidorSQLB3 es 'Bascula19\SQLEXPRESS'
La estructura de la base de datos en sí, es la misma, la verdad no tengo idea de por qué pasa esto, alguien me puede apoyar??
